# Remotely view Android device from another Android device

Tags: android, vnc

I want to create a simple (?) system where an Android "master" tablet can at anytime connect to another "slave" Android tablet and literally show the slave's screen (mirror it's UI). For example, a parent wants to see what his kid is doing on the tablet.

The tablets are assumed to be connected to the same LAN, so no Internet access is required.

I have looked into android-vnc-server and android-vnc-viewer but they don't seem to be what I am looking for.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use team viewer?

Comment: @Ndupza maybe I wasn't clear, I'm looking to implement an app that does this

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the exact answer , i am just trying to define an approach here :-
So, in VNC based application what u do is , u get the screenshot of the device and send that screenshot to another device to display , but the whole process goes on high rate.
Now for security reasons in non-rooted android phones, u can't capture the screen shot of other apps , but if your phone is unlocked/rooted then u can run a shell command to captuer the phone image using:
`adb shell screencap`

usage:-

```
adb shell screencap -h
usage: screencap [-hp] [FILENAME]
   -h: this message
   -p: save the file as a png.
If FILENAME ends with .png it will be saved as a png.
If FILENAME is not given, the results will be printed to stdout.
```

now u just have to create a java process and execute that command in it , open the standard input stream of that process and read the imagefile as bytes and send this bytes to other device to reconstruct and display the image.

so the recipe will involve : 
1. a background service which will keep capturing the image ,
 2. a process to execute shell command 
 3. datastructure to hold the bytes read from process's input stream and 
4. procedure to transfer those values over network.

to execute the shell command :-

```
 Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su screencap");
 DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());
```

use this inputStream to read the result , save and transfer this result over the network !!